# moto not mocking ec2.describe_security_groups function call

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, testing, moto

```
import boto3
....
@mock_ec2
def test_mocking_getting_security_groups(self):
    region = 'us-east-2'
    vpc_security_group_id = 'default'


    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
    ec2_client = session.client('ec2', region)
    print(ec2_client.describe_security_groups())
    print(ec2_client.describe_security_groups(GroupIds=['sg-3e2bcf04']))
```

I have this test case and the first prints

```
{'SecurityGroups': [{'Description': 'default group', 'GroupName': 'default', 'IpPermissions': [], 'OwnerId': '123456789012', 'GroupId': 'sg-0b13b4ba', 'IpPermissionsEgress': [{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}], 'Tags': []}, {'Description': 'default VPC security group', 'GroupName': 'default', 'IpPermissions': [], 'OwnerId': '123456789012', 'GroupId': 'sg-df20018b', 'IpPermissionsEgress': [{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}], 'Tags': [], 'VpcId': 'vpc-1940c2c1'}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '59dbff89-35bd-4eac-99ed-be587EXAMPLE', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'amazon.com'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

which seems fine, seems like it's the properly mocked response. But then: `ec2_client.describe_security_groups(GroupIds=['sg-3e2bcf04'])` fails

```
E           botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidGroup.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation: The security group '{'sg-3e2bcf04'}' does not exist
```

Is there something else I need to mock out?

EDIT: 
It seems like it generates a non predictable random GroupID at every run. Any idea how to lock it down?

Comment: In your first print's output it doesn't show group-id ```sg-3e2bcf04``` but not sure why you are searching that ID when it doesn't exist. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Shakeel seems like it's randomly generated. Every single run gets me a different id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create one SG and can describe the created one. 
[source](https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/e00af2f73cb7d27c3755f18b2161b9acbd8ca8aa/tests/test_ec2/test_security_groups.py)

```
import boto3
from moto import mock_ec2


@mock_ec2
def test_mocking_getting_security_groups():
    region = 'us-east-2'
    vpc_security_group_id = 'default'
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='shakeel_aws')
    ec2_client = session.client('ec2', region)

    sg = ec2_client.create_security_group(GroupName="test-sg", Description="Test SG")
    print(sg["GroupId"])
    print(ec2_client.describe_security_groups())
    print(ec2_client.describe_security_groups(GroupIds=[sg["GroupId"]]))


test_mocking_getting_security_groups()
```

Output:

```
sg-27a9b9cf
{'SecurityGroups': [{'Description': 'default group', 'GroupName': 'default', 'IpPermissions': [], 'OwnerId': '123456789012', 'GroupId': 'sg-7af61a21', 'IpPermissionsEgress': [{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}], 'Tags': []}, {'Description': 'Test SG', 'GroupName': 'test-sg', 'IpPermissions': [], 'OwnerId': '123456789012', 'GroupId': 'sg-27a9b9cf', 'IpPermissionsEgress': [{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}], 'Tags': []}, {'Description': 'default VPC security group', 'GroupName': 'default', 'IpPermissions': [], 'OwnerId': '123456789012', 'GroupId': 'sg-4ec8ebd5', 'IpPermissionsEgress': [{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}], 'Tags': [], 'VpcId': 'vpc-b1373745'}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '59dbff89-35bd-4eac-99ed-be587EXAMPLE', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'amazon.com'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
{'SecurityGroups': [{'Description': 'Test SG', 'GroupName': 'test-sg', 'IpPermissions': [], 'OwnerId': '123456789012', 'GroupId': 'sg-27a9b9cf', 'IpPermissionsEgress': [{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}], 'Tags': []}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '59dbff89-35bd-4eac-99ed-be587EXAMPLE', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'amazon.com'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```