# moto can't mock ec2 with securitygroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-ec2, boto3, moto

I recently asked this question:

[moto unit test EC2 - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72842891/moto-unit-test-ec2-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-id)

I now have at least found out about why this error occurs.

I call `ec2.run_instances()` with multiple parameters, like this:

```
ec2.run_instances(
        ImageId=IMAGE_ID,
        MinCount=count,
        MaxCount=count,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        KeyName=KEY_NAME,
        SecurityGroupIds=[SECURITY_GROUP_ID]
    )
```

When trying to mock this like shown in my other question, I get an error because it can't find the specified securityGroupId.

When I comment out the `SecurityGrouoIds` like so:

```
...
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        KeyName=KEY_NAME,
        #SecurityGroupIds=[SECURITY_GROUP_ID]
    )
...
```

the `moto` test runs fine.

How can I add the securityGroup to the instance? I have tried to use the solution from
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568476/moto-not-mocking-ec2-describe-security-groups-function-call) question, but it didn't work out for me.

Does anyone have an Idea about how to mock / add the securityGroup to the ec2 mock?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

The test itself looks like this:

```
 @mock_ec2
    def test_create_instances_with_decorator(self):
        instance_count = 1
        image_id = 'ami-0df635fd7dea02388'
        client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
        client.create_security_group(Description="my-test-group",GroupName="launch-wizard-1")
        mngr = aws_manager()
        mngr.launchInstances(2)
        instances = client.describe_instances()['Reservations'][0]['Instances']
        print(instances)
        assert len(instances) == 2
        assert instances[0]['ImageId'] == image_id
```

And the code to be tested looks like this:

```
SECURITY_GROUP_ID = "sg-0dc0a634bc153adc8"
REGION_NAME = "eu-central-1"
INSTANCE_TYPE = "t2.micro"
class aws_manager:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION_NAME)
        self.running_instances = []

    def launchInstances(self, count: int):

            instances = self.ec2.run_instances(
                ImageId=IMAGE_ID,
                MinCount=count,
                MaxCount=count,
                InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
                KeyName=KEY_NAME,
                SecurityGroupIds=[SECURITY_GROUP_ID]
            )["Instances"][0]
```

Comment: Where does `SECURITY_GROUP_ID` come from? The security group has to be created first (using ec2.create_security_group`), then it should work fine. If you are creating it first, can you post a small reproducible test case?

Comment: Hello @BertBlommers , `SECURITY_GROUP_ID` = `sg-0dc0a634bc153adc8` in my case. This is the id of the `securitygroup`, that I want to use for each EC2 instance that is being created `launchInstances(count)`, so this is a required parameter for me. I have set it up before online in the EC2 Management Console. 
I edited the question and added some code.

Comment: @codedor where in your code is that assignment? It is not in anything you have posted.

Comment: Side note, for creating resources like ec2 instances, I highly recommend using an infrastructure as code system such as Cloudformation or Terraform. These system are declarative rather than imperative and they keep track of the resources they have created.

Comment: @jordanm
I now added the assignment. Yeah that would be an alternative but shouldn't this work what I am trying to do?

Comment: It depends on how you import it, but you would need to use something like [unittest.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch). I would however recommend just changing your actual code so that security_upgrade_id is and instance variable of the aws_manager object. That will make it easy to override from tests.